# spawnSync('npm', ['install']) gives [Error: spawnSync npm ENOENT]

Tags: node.js

I am having an issue with spawnSync is giving me ENOENT with simple "npm install". Can someone please help me?

======= NODE SCRIPT ==========

`var child =   require('child_process').spawnSync('npm', ['install']);
 console.log(child.error);`

===== OUTPUT ==========

`[Error: spawnSync npm ENOENT]
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawnSync npm',
path: 'npm',
spawnargs: [ 'install' ]`

only on windows but not on OS X.

- This happens on

  - windows 7 x64
  - node version: 4.4.3
  - npm version: 2.15.1

Answer (score 21):

I figured out the issue. On Windows, some commands need to be suffixed with `.cmd` in order to work. In this example, this updated command works for me: 
`require('child_process').spawnSync('npm.cmd', ['install']);`

Comment: This fixed the error but the spawnSync() command just hangs now.  No return, no activity.  I was doing 'npm install' too (on Win 10 Pro).

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use [cross-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn) to make it work cross-platform

Comment: I couldn't make this work however I'm new to NodeJS.  I was trying to write a platform-independent script so there isn't a 'package.json' to save dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand your cause and effect about "writing a platform-independent script" and "there isn't  package.json".

Comment: Instead of 'setup.ps1' or 'setup.sh' I was trying to write 'setup.js'.  I understand to have project dependencies one needs 'package.json' which is created by 'npm init', which I didn't want to do.  I was hoping to write a script that only depended on globally installed packages and built-ins.  Again, I'm fairly new to NodeJS.

Comment: cross-spawn is not a package nodejs will install for you so you need to install it yourself, npm i -g cross-spawn (to install it globally)

Comment: Writing a cross platform script is totally reasonable and people have been using Python for this purpose for ages. You should not need external dependencies to achieve that - however I have also run into this problem, did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by specifying the shell to be the v1 32-bit Powershell executable.

I don't know if there is a more reliable method of getting the Powershell executable path, but this is what I did:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')

const shell = process.platform === 'win32' 
  ? 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe' 
  : undefined

const r0 = spawnSync('pnpm', ['run', 'build'], {
  cwd: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'projects', 'project-name'),
  env: process.env,
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell
})

if (r0.error) {
  console.log(r0.error)
  process.exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `shell` and `encoding` option.

```js
var child = require('child_process').spawnSync('npm', ['install'],
   {shell:true, encoding:'utf-8'});
console.log(child.error);
```